# How to set google experimental audio media constraints on getUserMedia

Tags: webrtc, constraints, getusermedia, echo-cancellation

When using Google Meet, there are several unpublished audio constraints that get set.  Looking at webrtc-internals shows the audio constraints as:

`{deviceId: {exact: ["default"]}, advanced: [{googEchoCancellation: {exact: true}}, {googExperimentalEchoCancellation: {exact: true}}, {autoGainControl: {exact: true}}, {noiseSuppression: {exact: true}}, {googHighpassFilter: {exact: true}}, {googAudioMirroring: {exact: true}}]}`

I'm currently having issues with the standard echo cancellation in Chrome that I do not experience when using Google Meet.  So I want to run some tests enabling the googEchoCancellation and googExperimentalEchoCancellation, however when I set those constraints in getUserMedia they do not get applied.  Instead looking at webrtc-internals shows my constraints as:

`{deviceId: {exact: ["default"]}, advanced: [{}, {}, {autoGainControl: {exact: true}}, {noiseSuppression: {exact: true}}, {}, {}]}`

Chrome is ignoring the goog* specific constraints when I try to set them, but Meet is able to set them.

I can see these constraints exist in Chrome's source code at:
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/modules/mediastream/media_constraints.cc

But I can't figure out how to set them.

So my question is how does Google Meet set those additional audio constraints?

I have tried setting the constraints in getUserMedia as:

`let gum = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({deviceId: {exact: ["default"]}, advanced: [{googEchoCancellation: {exact: true}}, {googExperimentalEchoCancellation: {exact: true}}, {autoGainControl: {exact: true}}, {noiseSuppression: {exact: true}}, {googHighpassFilter: {exact: true}}, {googAudioMirroring: {exact: true}}]})`

I have also tried applying them to the audio track directly with:

`let tracks = await gum.getAudioTracks() await tracks[0].applyConstraints({advanced: [{googEchoCancellation: {exact: true}}, {googExperimentalEchoCancellation: {exact: true}}, {autoGainControl: {exact: true}}, {noiseSuppression: {exact: true}}, {googHighpassFilter: {exact: true}}, {googAudioMirroring: {exact: true}}]})`

Neither of these approaches set the googEchoCancellation or googExperimentalEchoCancellation.